# Robots.txt, disallow multilanguage URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, robots.txt

I have a public page that is not supposed be possible for users to sign into. So I have a url that there is no link to and you have to enter manually and then sign in.

The url is multilanguage however, so it can be "/SV/Account/Logon" or "/EN/Account/Logon" etc etc. Can I disable this url to be indexed for all languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This url might help you http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html. There will be no wildcard exclusion in your case you will have to add all the language specific login urls in robot.txt

**Update**

you can put `Disallow: /folder/subfolder/` or `Disallow: /folder/` in your robots.txt file

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read that and do not wan't to do this. For example other users might add more languages using the admin interface and they do not know how to edit the robots.txt. Perhaps I can edit it from my code when adding more languages

Comment: @Oskar you can also consider moving such pages under a single folder and just add that folder in the exceptions list in robots.txt

Comment: @ajay_whiz They are all under the same folder. But can I write folders? I thought the URLs where the only thing affecting this

Comment: @Oskar yes, you can put as `Disallow: /folder/subfolder/` or `Disallow: /folder/`

Comment: @ajay_whiz Thanks, please post an answer so I can accept it :)